# How to get the value flag in JSON

Tags: java, json

I am new to JSON. I have the following JSON object

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "name": {
            "id": 49,
            "name": "basha",
            "description": "",
            "owner": "cpee",
            "projectUsers": [],
            "flag": null
        },
        "flag": "add"
    }
]
}
```

I want to get the flag value (`"add"`), but I am getting `null`.
In java I am trying to get the value using this code:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode
jsonNode.get("data").get("flag");
```

As requested, here is more of my Java code

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
projectDTO = mapper.readValue(json.get("data").get(0), ProjectDetailsDTO.class);
```

readValue will parse the JSON object to Java specific object

Comment: How are you trying to access `flag`? The JSON looks okay, so it's probably the way you're accessing it's causing the problem.

Comment: I updated the question. added how I accessed the flag in java @EricAlberson

Comment: It might help if you would put all the code you're using to process the JSON string and get the flag value, not just the last line of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
json.get("data").get(0).get("flag");
```

data is an array with only 1 item. and in that item you can get flag by above expression

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: outer flag value can access with the given expression. so just gave the line which will be helpful @nKn

Comment: Hey thanks pal..this is wht I want read json value. But have to check will it work or not. Will chk on monday

Answer (score 1):

Data is an array...

```
   org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode
    jsonNode.get("data")[0] .get("flag");


 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   projectDTO =mapper.readValue(json.get("data").get(0), ProjectDetailsDTO.class);
    Flag=mapper.readValue(projectDTO.get("flag", ProjectDetailsDTO.class )) ;
```

Comment: readValueproductDTO is our own method to parse? readvalue is from jackson library

Comment: using mapper.readValue it converts the json structure to the given java class, Here its ProjectDetailsDTO. Once its parsed to that object we can simply use ProjectDTO.getFlag(). The thing is I want to get that before parsing it to java object. I just added extra java code. My problem is reading it directly from json